# In Rails, how can I set a cookie's Max-Age?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, cookies

In Rails 3.2.8, you can [write a cookie](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) like this:

```
cookies[:login] = {
  :value   => "XJ-122",
  :expires => 1.hour.from_now
}
```

The docs say that these are the available option symbols:

```
:value
:path
:domain
:expires
:secure
:httponly
```

I would expect `:max_age` to be available as an option too, but perhaps [user agent support is not widespread enough yet (?)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.2) to warrant including it.

So how should I set a cookie's [`Max-Age`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age) in Rails?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? *(I'm just curious)*

Comment: I want to do this in a module used across several local and remote applications whose time configuration is inconsistent. `Max-Age` will make that simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I read over [the Rails source code for ActionDispatch::Cookies](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb). If you look at [how the `handle_options` method is used](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L172) you will see that even options not specified in the documentation are passed through. Rails usually passes options around quite liberally, with the philosophy that, somewhere down the line, a method will know what to do with the left-over options.

So, I would suggest that you give it a try with the `:max_age` option, even though it is not documented, and see what happens.

Note: Rails relies on [Rack to set the cookie header](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L221), so if for some reason the "Max-Age" "Set-Cookie" header **is** being passed to Rack but is **not** being passed through, I would ask over on the Github Rack issue tracker.

Update #1: there has been at least one pull request having to do with `Max-Age` and Rack, but I'm not sure it is relevant. If the above doesn't work, I think you may want to discuss on the Rack ticket tracker as I mention above.

Update #2: Have you looked at the [Rack::Cache](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache) middleware? It may be of use.

Comment: Looks like ultimately `:max_age`, `:'max-age'` and `'Max-Age'` (I tried all three) are ignored by Rack. All these options are indeed passed along to `::Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!` (actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:231), where they are ignored.

Comment: If you post a ticket to Rack -- or find a workaround -- will you share it here?

Comment: I [added `:max_age` to my Rack fork](https://github.com/matthewtoast/rack/commit/6779daa5646b8de27efdf0894453fb36bd36630d). Not sure if I should submit it as a pull request though since [a similar pull request was just closed](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/264).

Comment: Update: My pull request was [merged into rack/rack master](https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/74e0acd36353cf619bf56fce17bcb9ef1ab30547).

Comment: @mtoast Thanks for the PR and updating us here!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - Just summarizing all of the above

```
cookies["foo"] = {value: "bar", max_age: 2.minutes}
```

Rails has no awareness of :max_age and the option is not documented.
However, Rails passes unrecognized options through to the underlying Rack middleware.  Rack supports :max_age (underscored) and renders the Set-Cookie header properly.